# One-to-many relation need to define a valid foreign key error

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to make a webapp and I have a simple data model with a one to many relation. I tried sticking to the documentation of gorm and from my understanding this should work:

```
package dbModels

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type Post struct {
    gorm.Model
    Text string
    Likes int
    Comments []Comment 
}

type Comment struct {
    gorm.Model
    Text string
    Likes int
    PostID uint
}
```

I'm migrating these models like that:

```
db.AutoMigrate(&dbModels.Post{}, &dbModels.Comment{})
```

Then I want to put this object in post:

```
func (r *mutationResolver) CreatePost(ctx context.Context, input model.PostInput) (*model.Post, error) {
    var items []*model.Comment
    post := model.Post{
        Text:     input.Text,
        Likes:    0,
        Comments: items,
    }
    r.DB.Create(&post)
    return &post, nil
}
```

however I get the following error:

```
2021/01/31 11:23:01 /home/felix/Projekte/GoReact/server/graph/schema.resolvers.go:21 invalid field found for struct github.com/blamefelix/TwitterClone/graph/model.Post's field Comments, need to define a valid foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface
```

I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. From the gorm documentation I thought the relation would get managed by gorm if I put it like that? My suspicion is, that I put the wrong data in?

Comment: I grabbed your model definitions and tested them, and they work just fine. In this CreatePost you're not checking the Error from the Create call, so how do you know this is the point in the code that caused the error message?

Just double checking also, I'm wondering why your CreatePost code assigns a `[]*model.Comment` to the Comments field, since it's defined in module dbModels, and as a slice of struct, not a slice of pointer to struct.

Comment: Yeah so basically I wanted to use different models for the orm and for gql. My thought was that I might want to have some stuff in the backend state that does not need to be in the database. Thats why I assigned model.Comment. I've managed to fix this error by just using my graphql models as orm models. So the problem must have been that I put the wrong data into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to fix it by using the same model for graphql and gorm. The problem must have been that I've pased the wrong data into the db create function

Comment: Can you shed some light into this? I am facing the same issue but mine is a simple CRUD app